# Creating tabs with Angular2 material

Tags: angular

I want to create vertical tabs with Angular2 I read there is a way to do this with Angular [Material](https://material.angular.io/)
Well how I need to install Material to my exist application and how can I create a tab with that within a component?

```
var isPublic = typeof window != "undefined";

/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': (isPublic) ? '/' : 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'client',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
            'angular2-jwt':               'npm:angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js',
            'ng-semantic':                'npm:ng-semantic'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'ng-semantic': {
                main: 'ng-semantic',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean how to install the material npm package? According to their site its

```
npm install --save @angular/material
```

Then obviously run `npm install`

The use of the module in app.module.ts:

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
// other imports 
@NgModule({
  imports: [MaterialModule.forRoot()],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And then there's a demo app for using the nav. I'm not going to post all the code here, since it would be much code, even though I know that would probably be best since links can change...

[Materia Github demo app](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/demo-app/demo-app)

But there are several other solutions out there as well, e.g [angular2-tabs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-tabs) Seems simple enough:

```
npm install angular2-tabs --save
```

HTML:

```
<an-tablist #list="anTabList" anListClass="diff-class"></an-tablist>
<an-tabs [anList]="list">
    <div *anTabDefault="tabOne">
        The Contents of Tab one
        <div anNextTab="hello">Next</div>
    </div>
    <div *anTab="'hello'">
        The Contents of Tab Two
        <div [anNextTab]="tabOne"></div>
    </div>
</an-tabs>
```

Controller:

```
import {ANGULAR_TABS_DIRECTIVES, TabInterface} from "angular2-tabs/core";

@Component({
    ...
    directives: [ANGULAR_TABS_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class IndexComponent {
    tabOne: TabInterface = {id: "test", title: 'test Title', canActivate: () => {return true;}}
}
```

Another solution: 
[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/0YKxZl3KksWy2lRRta6x/)